# Strange Pillow exception while saving cropped image

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

We have the following code:

```
img = Image.open(FileSystemStorage().path(relpath))

coords = [
          cd['crop_start_x'],
          cd['crop_start_y'],
          cd['crop_end_x'],
          cd['crop_end_y']   
          ]

cropped_img = img.crop(coords)
cropped_path = "%s-cropped%s" % os.path.splitext(relpath)
tasks.delete_temporary_file.delay(fss.path(relpath))
cropped_img.save(fss.path(cropped_path))
```

When trying to save the cropped image, we get a strange "Not a valid number of quantization tables. Should be between 1 and 4." exception, just in one of our environments. 
The strangest part is that the code might work sometimes *even though the crop or the image doesn't change*

Has anyone a lead on this?

We are using Pillow 2.8.1, python 2.7.6 and Ubuntu server 12.04

Comment: Anything different about that environment?

Comment: We've checked everything.. form OS packages to the Pillow version, tried Pillow reinstalls and such... still no luck

Comment: Do you have any PIL installs that might be conflicting with Pillow?

Comment: How did you import the class Image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, the problem originated on a conflicting PIL installation in one of the app servers. It was hard to find since they were hiding behind a load balancer, so the error would pop out *sometimes*

When we issued `pip freeze` on the console, we found out that in one of the servers we had both PIL and Pillow installed.

Upon removing both of them and reinstalling Pillow, we solved the issue.

Just to make it clear:

```
pip uninstall PIL
pip uninstall Pillow
pip install Pillow
```

And then, just restart the web server.

As others have stated, another possible cause is the use of:

```
import Image
```

That statement works only for PIL and should be avoided.
We should always use:

```
from PIL import Image
```

Comment: And that's what happens when a drop-in replacement adopts the same package name of an existing module :\